# How to use Solve such that the denominator is left untouched?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm currently solving a system of $3$ equations, $3$ unknowns and several parameters. Although the code I'm using takes some time in my computer and generates a warning, it solves the problem. See the code below:

```
Rationalize[FullSimplify[Solve[{M==x-(p/3)*(N+p*(x-M-p*O-(1-p)*\[Epsilon])+(1-p)*\[Gamma]+p*(x-O-p*M-(1-p)*\[Beta])+(1-p)*\[Delta])-(p/3)*(O+p*(x-M-p*N-(1-p)*\[Gamma])+(1-p)*\[Epsilon]+p*(x-N-p*M-(1-p)*\[Alpha])+(1-p)*\[Mu])-(1-p)*\[Gamma]-(1-p)*\[Epsilon], 
N==x-(p/3)*(M+p*(x-N-p*O-(1-p)*\[Mu])+(1-p)*\[Alpha]+p*(x-O-p*N-(1-p)*\[Delta])+(1-p)*\[Beta])-(p/3)*(O+p*(x-N-p*M-(1-p)*\[Alpha])+(1-p)*\[Epsilon]+p*(x-M-p*N-(1-p)*\[Gamma])+(1-p)*\[Mu])-(1-p)*\[Alpha]-(1-p)*\[Mu], 
O==x-(p/3)*(M+p*(x-N-p*O-(1-p)*\[Mu])+(1-p)*\[Alpha]+p*(x-O-p*N-(1-p)*\[Delta])+(1-p)*\[Beta])-(p/3)*(N+p*(x-M-p*O-(1-p)*\[Epsilon])+(1-p)*\[Gamma]+p*(x-O-p*M-(1-p)*\[Beta])+(1-p)*\[Delta])-(1-p)*\[Beta]-(1-p)*\[Delta]},{M, N, O},MaxExtraConditions->Automatic]]]
```

Where $p\in[0,1)$. The output Mathematica gives is very ugly in the denominator. For reasons related to the theoretical problem I'm considering, I'd really like to get the solution to the previous system of equations with a constant in the denominator (or, at least, without any $p$ in the denominator). *Assuming that this is possible*, **how do I achieve so?**

Comment: 1) don't use `N,O`. 2) Can you please reduce this to a minimal-working-example?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Since I'm new to Mathematica, let me ask: 1) Why? What should I use then? Also, 2) I'd love to, but that would mean finding a similar yet shorter system of equations in which the $p$, despite not being in the denominator of any of the original equations, ends up in the denominator. I'm sure it can be done, but I can't think of any better strategy than "trial and error" until I come up with one such system of equations. I can try to do that, but it's not very efficient and I don't know how much time it will take me to do so.

Comment: 1) `N` and `O` are predefined functions, so you should not use those symbols. You can use `n` and `o` (more generally, try and use lower case letters). 2) Well, you don't *have* to reduce your question, but if you do so, you're more likely to get good answers. If you think you can reduce it, it'll be better for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your comment and your advise. It's a bit late where I live; I'll try to reduce it tomorrow as soon as I have some time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`N`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) and [`O`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/O.html) are reserved words in Mathematica and cannot be used as your variables. As a general rule, user-defined names should start with a lower case letter since built-in names all start with an upper case letter (or `$`).

```
eqns = {mM == 
    x - 1/3 p (nN + 
        p (x - mM - p oO - (1 - p) ϵ) + (1 - p) γ + 
        p (x - oO - p mM - (1 - p) β) + (1 - p) δ) - 
     1/3 p (oO + p (x - mM - p nN - (1 - p) γ) + (1 - p) ϵ + 
        p (x - nN - p mM - (1 - p) α) + (1 - p) μ) - (1 - 
        p) γ - (1 - p) ϵ, 
   nN == x - 
     1/3 p (mM + p (x - nN - p oO - (1 - p) μ) + (1 - p) α + 
        p (x - oO - p nN - (1 - p) δ) + (1 - p) β) - 
     1/3 p (oO + p (x - nN - p mM - (1 - p) α) + (1 - p) ϵ + 
        p (x - mM - p nN - (1 - p) γ) + (1 - p) μ) - (1 - 
        p) α - (1 - p) μ, 
   oO == x - 
     1/3 p (mM + p (x - nN - p oO - (1 - p) μ) + (1 - p) α + 
        p (x - oO - p nN - (1 - p) δ) + (1 - p) β) - 
     1/3 p (nN + p (x - mM - p oO - (1 - p) ϵ) + (1 - p) γ + 
        p (x - oO - p mM - (1 - p) β) + (1 - p) δ) - (1 - 
        p) β - (1 - p) δ};

(sol = Solve[eqns, {mM, nN, oO}][[1]] // FullSimplify) // Column
```

[image]

Verifying solution

```
eqns /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)
```

All of the terms have a common, relatively simple denominator

```
Denominator[{mM, nN, oO} /. sol] // Union

(* {(3 + p (2 + p)) (-3 + 2 p (-1 + 2 p (1 + p)))} *)
```

Note that the denominator is not a constant

```
denom = %[[1]];
```

Also, the denominator has a zero for `p` in the interval `[0,1)`

```
singular = Solve[denom == 0, p, Reals][[1]] // ToRadicals // Simplify

(* {p -> 1/6 (-2 + 10^(1/3) + 10^(2/3))} *)
```

Verifying,

```
denom /. singular // Simplify

(* 0 *)
```

The approximate numeric value of `p` for the zero in the denominator is

```
singular // N

(* {p -> 0.799337} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. My goal is to achieve, **if possible**, a result for mM, nN and oO in which $p$ is **not** in the denominator. I don't see such a thing in your answer. Shall I then assume that what I desire cannot be done? Or am I missing the whole point of your answer?

Comment: @BobHanlon minor nitpick: to be sure `singular` is really a singularity, you have to check whether the numerator vanishes too.

Comment: The statement "Note that the denominator is not a constant" was intended to point out that `p` will be in the denominator. The values for `mM, nN, and oO` are determined by the equations. Perhaps there are some fortuitous choices of the parameters `{x, \[Alpha], \[Beta], \[Gamma], \[Delta], \[Epsilon], \[Mu]}` that will result in cancellation of the denominator, For example the degenerate case of `{x -> 0, \[Alpha] -> 0, \[Beta] -> 0, \[Gamma] -> 0, \[Delta] -> 
  0, \[Epsilon] -> 0, \[Mu] -> 0}`

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform - Yes, you are correct.